# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError converting addEventListener to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, xml-rpc

I have a simple webpage developed that I use to send text input to an XML RPC server.  I got the code working in Javascript but now I'm trying to convert it all to Typescript and use promises with async/await.  This is as a learning experiment.  It's proving to be a little difficult at my current experience level.

Previous working Javascript code:

```
import "./mimic.js";
function makeComment() {
    const method = "MakeComm";
    let request = new XmlRpcRequest("http://localhost:1337/RPC2", method);
    request.addParam(document.getElementById("n1")).value;
    request.addParam(document.getElementById("n2")).value;
    let response = request.send();
    console.log(response);
}
```

As I said above, this function communicates correctly with the XML RPC server.  Here is my converted Typescript code:

```
import "./mimic.js";
const updateCommentBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById(
    'makeComment',) as HTMLButtonElement;

updateCommentBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const method = "MakeComm";
    let request:any = new XmlRpcRequest("http://localhost:1337/RPC2", method);
    request.addParam(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("n1")).value;
    request.addParam(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("n2")).value;
    let response = await request.send();
    console.log(response);
});
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: XmlRpcRequest is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (fileChange.ts:36)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (fileChange.ts:34)
```

The XmlRpcRequest call is a function contained in ./mimic.js.

My HTML for the Typescript version:

```
<p>Make Comment:</p>
<input type="text" id="n1"/>
<input type="text" id="n2"/>
<button id="makeComment">Update Comment</button>
```

EDIT:
mimic.js defines XmlRpcRequest as follows:

```
function XmlRpcRequest(url, method) {
    this.serviceUrl = url;
    this.methodName = method;
    this.crossDomain = false;
    this.withCredentials = false;   
    this.params = [];
    this.headers = {};
};
```

Comment: what does `request.send()` return?

Comment: is XmlRpcRequest exported in mimic.js?  Perhaps import {XmlRpcRequest} from "./mimic.js" ?

Comment: XmlRpcRequest does not appear exported in mimic.js.  (It was developed some time ago).  I got file ".../mimic.js" is not a module.

Comment: @DanielA.White  I get no output from request.send.  It fails on exception before that point.

Comment: Where is XmlRpcRequest located? It's clear that the it is not visible in the scripts context so you should check where it's located and make it visible for the script.

Comment: Perhaps you'd have to declare the [typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for that XmlRpcRequest class

Comment: XmlRpcRequest is the function name in mimic.js located in my src directory.  It's odd that it worked in Javascript but not compatible with Typescript.  File found here:  http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I thought the same @lenilsondc, however because it is old javascript, there is no class XmlRpcRequest for type it to.  I tried typing the return variable to XmlRpcRequest and the linter complained

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's old javascript, the class structure is still the same although declared like that, all you have to do is to make XmlRpcRequest visible globally (on window) and if necessary, create a type definition for it so that you can import it and make typescript pretend it's a real module with real typescript classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding your code

You should export the function like this in mimic.js

```
export const XmlRpcRequest = (url, method) => {
    this.serviceUrl = url;
    this.methodName = method;
    this.crossDomain = false;
    this.withCredentials = false;   
    this.params = [];
    this.headers = {};
};
```

and import it

```
import { XmlRpcRequest } from "./mimic";
```

If your typescript linter is giving you gyp you could add definitions for the arguments like so:

```
  export const XmlRpcRequest = (url: string, method: string) => {
        this.serviceUrl = url;
        this.methodName = method;
        this.crossDomain = false;
        this.withCredentials = false;   
        this.params = [];
        this.headers = {};
  };
```

Comment: I've updated the main post with how mimic.js defines XmlRpcRequest

Comment: Seems like something of a typescript problem rather than a javascript problem.  How would you resolve this kind of issue?

Comment: This worked!  Interestingly, I had to restart VS Code first though...  It was still complaining about the environment.  Now it's pointing to a similar issue with the request.addParam prototype (undefined).  I suppose I need to define it as an "export const" too?

Comment: Its syntax is a little different...  XmlRpcRequest.prototype.addParam=function(...)

Comment: I should say, the above compiles but provide an error in the console log.  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addParam' of undefined"

Comment: Please bear with me I have to get some sleep ill come back to this in morning.. can you show your new error in comments plz?

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help.  I pasted the new error above.

Comment: Fat arrows dont work with imported function prototypes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099354/exporting-javascript-file-to-typescript/54099533#54099533