# How to call JavaScript from TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript file that I want to call from typescript.  I fixed one import problem and modified the base function to be recognized in tsc, however, I'm still facing an issue recognizing a declared function prototype in the javascript file.

I do have `"allowJs": true`.

Here is my fileTransfer.ts:

```
import { XmlRpcRequest } from "./mimic";
const updateCommentBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById(
    'makeComment',) as HTMLButtonElement;

updateCommentBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const method = "MakeComm";
    let request:any = XmlRpcRequest("http://localhost:1337/RPC2", method);
    request.addParam(document.getElementById("n1")).value;
    request.addParam(document.getElementById("n2")).value;
    let response = await request.send();
    console.log(response);
});
```

And here are the relevant portions of the mimic.js file that I'm importing:

```
export const XmlRpcRequest = (url, method) => {
    this.serviceUrl = url;
    this.methodName = method;
    this.crossDomain = false;
    this.withCredentials = false;   
    this.params = [];
    this.headers = {};
};

XmlRpcRequest.prototype.addParam = (data) => {
    // Vars
    var type = typeof data;

    switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
    case "function":
        return;
    case "object":
        if (!data.constructor.name){
            return;
        }   
    }
    this.params.push(data);
};
```

tsc compiles the project and the linter does not flag any errors. But, I get the following error in Chrome's console:

```
mimic.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addParam' of undefined
```

This seems to me like an issue with accessing the exported function's prototype but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.  I should mention that I can run the file just fine in a Javascript only application, I only face this issue going to the Typescript environment.

Comment: `XmlRpcRequest` doesn't return anything. you need to invoke it with `new`

Comment: I tried that (and I needed new for the Javascript version too), however, I get the following error when I put     new XmlRpcRequest:  'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature in TypeScript, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: consider making it a `class`, not a prototype class.

Comment: Sidenote: `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: @Thomas I'm sorry, I'm not getting your reference to the code?

Comment: If `data === null` then `if (!data.constructor.name){` will throw an error. Don't know wether this is an issue for your code; just something that I noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer why you're unable to use fat arrow syntax if you want to access prototype:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/does-arrow-function-syntax-works-for-prototype

Here's two additional explanations about `this` with fat arrow syntax:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Use_of_prototype_property

As a resolution you need to define it with normal function declaration:

`const XmlRpcRequest = function(url, method) { ... }`

Alternatively, you could use **class**:

```
class XmlRpcRequest {
  constructor(url, method) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You are awesome!  It was the fat arrows!

Comment: In case other read this, I also needed to add:  new (XmlRpcRequest as any)